# My real-time React Native list is very slow to update

Tags: arrays, reactjs, listview, react-native

I need a list in React Native that will update when a socket.io sends data in.

I have everything set up and have tried:

- ListView
- FlatList and
- My own basic JavaScript array of components

The list is 600 long and the data needs to be dynamic (around 3 times/second socket.io data comes in and I update the corresponding index of the list). The problem comes in when I scroll down everything slows down a lot and comes to a halt and the list stops updating.

The list basically can't handle more than 40 of my light weight components. Is there a better way here to be updating the list.

Any trick so it renders correctly and can keep up with the incoming data?

Comment: Have you tried setting `removeClippedSubviews = {true}` in the listview/scrollview props? I believe it improves performance for such a large array of items

Comment: Hey Ryan, I did try that and didn't see a noticeable difference. Maybe helped a little though. What is annoying me is that I can make a plain javascript array and render all 600 datapoints in <Text> </Text> and the app keeps up and the instance the socket.io data is pulled in it appears on screen. But when I try to send this data in as a prop to a child component (which is a super simple component) everything slows way down. Any other tips would be super helpful. Spent the last 14 hours on this and gotten nowhere. Is there a way to only render what's on screen not what is above or below?

Comment: could you post some code? ( as minimal as possible ). The removedClippedSubviews prop does that, only rendering items when they appear onscreen

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check if your registerServiceWorker.js is set up correctly and the service is functioning as intended. Check your index.js file to include

```
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

See also https:// goo.gl/KwvDNy for how it works.

See e.g. comment in the file:

```
// Our service worker won't work if PUBLIC_URL is on a different origin
// from what our page is served on. This might happen if a CDN is used to
// serve assets; see https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/2374
```